# Drive is Not Accessible. Access Denied

Tags: windows-10, external-hard-drive, file-permissions

Was accessing my external drive earlier today and then later went to access it and was getting 'H:\ is not accessible. Access Denied.' even though I had literally been in the device less than an hour earlier. I'm the local admin and have no other accounts on the pc it could be getting confused with.

Additionally I already tried to take ownership, through both the properties menu and adding it to the context menu. The properties says I don't have the permissions required to even see the current owner much less change it. The context menu way gives file isn't present.

It does have flashes where it's visible and where the properties way would try to set me as owner, but it couldn't actually do it because the drive closed off again before it could.

Also tried to use diskmgmt.msc to change the driveletter, gave parameter is incorrect.

I tried again to edit owner, it started to... then gave an error of 'the drive is not ready' and wouldn't go further. Now it tells me I don't even have access to try that anymore.

Comment: Have you tried restarting? Power cycling the external drive? It could be the drive is on the edge of failing. A SMART test would be good.

Comment: @davidpostill actually have restarted multiple times at this point, just found something online suggesting if it works in safe mode that Antivirus might be being... rude. Sure enough, safe mode accessing it works and after uninstalling the Antivirus (to switch, a new one is already installed), it was accessible outside of safemode. Still getting a new one when I can, but I seem to have found my culprit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue ended up being the Antivirus was blocking all access to the drive. Rebooting into safe mode diagnosed issue, uninstalling confirmed.

Comment: Just out of interest - which AV, so that I can avoid it

Comment: @mawg I believe it was panda cloud, first time I experienced it doing that to be fair.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem couple months back on an external drive that was good the day prior.

Navigate to the CMD prompt: Press WinKey+R, type CMD, ENTER.

Type into the prompt >chkdsk /f H:

Comment: This _might_ work - and can't hurt. Not that for Windows 10 it needs admin rights.